# Everytime I logoff/shutdown, my computer synchronizes to a remote folder

Tags: windows-xp, sync, domain

Every time I logoff or shutdown my pc at work, I get the following dialog:

[image: sync]

It is clearly a synchronization of some sort, it shows the path to the remote folder which is located in a PC in another department, I tried to check that folder physically but the owner of the machine would not help and he said something like "this machine has important files and I can not let you touch it". Now how do I reach the settings of this synchronization and know which files it's been synchronizing since ages? and how to I stop it?

Comment: If this is your machine at work, ask your sysadmin, it is clearly something that he/she has set up.

Comment: @terdon I asked, they said they do not do such a thing..

Comment: @HaLaBi - Contact your IT department and ask this how to stop the synchronization. Of course they might have set it up for a reason. Looking into this feature I found lots of google results with possible solutions. What have you tried that didn't work?  Ask your sysadmin is help you figure out how to disable it.

Comment: This machine is in other department. I called the IT and the guy told me they are not allowed to do such a thing. So it is not done by the IT. I should open a ticket for them to check it...

Comment: When things that appear dubious are happening on  your work PC, and IT says they shouldn't be, you shouldn't have to open a ticket, because they should already be all over that at that point. But if they are not (the old put clueless folks on the help desk scheme), by all means open a ticket. Or call the head of IT, or his boss. Somebody, somewhere is up to something they should not be - or the guy on the help desk is really out of the loop. Regardless, get it checked out pronto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307853) about using "Offline Files".

You don't have to have access to that computer.
You can browse on your own computer via "Network" to that computer and folder.

- You can enter `\\MACHINENAME\folder` in the address-bar and press enter
  (or browse via "Network" to this computer/folder.
- Go one level higher (so you can Right-Click that folder)
- un-check `Make Available Offline`

Now those files won't synchronize anymore at logoff.

**Edit**: If you don't use "Offline Files" I would disable it completely so this won't happen accidentally in the future (after doing the above):

- Click Start, and then click `My Computer`.
- On the `Tools` menu, click `Folder Options`.
- Click the `Offline Files`-tab.
- **un**-check the `Enable Offline Files` check box, and then click OK.